# Difference between using Gradle to add a library to my Android Studio Project versus as a Module

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

From what I can tell there are two main ways to add a library project to your Android Studio project that is not in the maven repo. Both can actually be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio). I am aware that doing it the module way is the Intellij way to do it (importing project to your modules and adding it as a dependency). It works quite nicely. But then there is the accepted answer way in the link above (copy and pasting the whole project in a library folder and adding it through gradle). Is doing it either way accomplishing the same thing in the "back" so the speak, or is there actually a difference? Is one way more preferred?

My reason for asking this is because I keep seeing both ways. On the one hand, since Android Studio is based on Intellij, the way [Intellij](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/sharing-android-source-code-and-resources-using-library-projects.html) does it makes sense. In fact the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/create-project.html#ReferencingLibraryModule) basically takes this behavior. On the other, the switch to Gradle isn't a bad way, although not as easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd suggest looking for the library in more than one Maven repository. The fact that the dependency is not in Maven Central doesn't mean it can't be found in [JCenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter), for example (more and more Android libraries authors publish to JCenter only since `jcenter()` is configured by default in Android Studio and [publishing to Maven Central is a huge PITA](http://blog.bintray.com/2014/02/11/bintray-as-pain-free-gateway-to-maven-central/)).

But let's assume the dependency can't be found in any public Maven repo.

Both ways you mentioned are suboptimal. Checking the `lib` folder to a source 
really bad idea. Source control, as the name implies is for sources.

With excellent and free [Binary Repository Managers out there](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Maven+Repository+Manager+Feature+Matrix) it's really easy to 'mavenize' all your dependencies and use them correctly.

If you don't want to manage Binary Repository server, you still have at least two options:

1. You can use [Artifactory SaaS offering](http://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/versions/#Cloud).
2. [Publish the dependency to your own repository in Bintray](https://bintray.com/howbintrayworks#page1) and then use if from Gradle. **That probably will be the easiest the the most correct way to deal with the problem**.